# Por que as opções de sinalização de perguntas do SO-en e do SO-pt são diferentes?

Tags: debate, sinalização

Eu costumo usar mais o StackOverflow em inglês do que o StackOverflow em português. Quando vou sinalizar questões no SO-pt eu sinto falta de algumas opções que estão disponíveis apenas na versão em inglês do site. Eu acredito que estas opções são bastante úteis.

Por exemplo, [esta questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211702/tutorial-selenium-ide-jenkins) postada hoje.
[image: Quesão]

Acredito que seja o tipo de questão que não deva estar no site, pois está apenas solicitando a indicação de um tutorial. No SO em inglês, eu poderia sinalizar esta questão como: *"should be closed..."* -> *"off-topic because..."* -> ***"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site"***. Essa opção pode ser vista na imagem abaixo.

[image: Opções do SO em inglês]

Ao tentar selecionar a opção correspondente no SO-pt percebi que ela simplesmente não existe. Ao seguir o caminho do menu pelas opções *"deveria ser fechada..."* -> *"fora de escopo..."*, não há nenhuma correspondência para ***"Questions asking us to recommend (...)"***, conforme pode ser visto na imagem abaixo.

[image: Opções do SO-pt]

Neste caso em específico, ter a opção de sinalizar uma questão que está solicitando um livro ou um tutorial seria bastante útil. Sem ela, ficou complicado encaixar a questão referida aqui em alguma categoria de "fora de escopo", mesmo sabendo que a questão não é apropriada...

Eu compreendo que algumas opções devem mesmo ser diferentes, como o é caso da opção de sinalizar questões não escritas em português que, obviamente, só faz sentido no SO-pt.

**Minha pergunta é:** existe algum motivo para essa discrepância entre as opções de sinalização SO-pt e do SO-en? Não seria melhor termos essas opções também no SO-pt, visto que fica difícil sinalizar algumas questões impróprias sem ela?

Comment: Curioso que pra mim aparece diferente. Deve ser diferente de acordo com a reputação ou porque sou moderador, mas não é comum ocorrer isto. Os textos são outros, não tem a penúltima opção (acredito que porque isso é recomendação de exclusão mais do que fechamento). Fora isto, cada site tem uma necessidade diferente e é mais ou menos personalizável. Nós temos ainda uma opção extra que está sendo guardada para uma necessidade mais forte, o que talvez já seja hora de usar.

Comment: Também pensei na possibilidade de ter relação com a reputação, pois no SO em inglês tenho uma reputação maior do que aqui. Eu compreendo que existem necessidades diferentes em cada site, porém essas opções me parecem bastante pertinentes. Tome como exemplo a questão que destaquei... Não é possível sinalizá-la sem a opção apropriada que destaquei e que existe no site em inglês. Neste caso, eu acabei nem sinalizando a questão, mesmo sabendo que ela é imprópria.

Comment: O primeiro motivo é pertinente.

Comment: Desculpe, mas qual é o primeiro motivo ao qual você se refere? E qual não seria pertinente no seu ponto de vista?

Comment: Deve ter haver com a reputação pois para mim também não aparece a opção **Abertamente fora do assunto**. No entanto aparece outra:  **Outro motivo(deixe um comentário explicando o que está errado)**.

Comment: Ao sinalizar, @ramaral, você clicou em *"deveria ser fecha..."* e depois em *"fora do escopo"*?

Comment: @EMBarbosa Sim, ***sinalizar*** -> ***deveria ser fechada...*** -> ***fora de escopo...***

Comment: @ramaral então deve ser mesmo uma lista dinâmica de motivos de acordo com a reputação. Pra mim eu vejo a mesma coisa que o Bruno.